# My clock has disappeared

Tags: indicator

So I have looked online (believe it or not) and I can't seem to find anything to help me with my issue. My clock just disappeared. Here's a screenshot!

[image: disappeared clock]

Comment: I had the same experience after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10. It's one of the reasons why I'm not longer on 13.10.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the said question. This is not happening in Gnome, but in Unity. FWIW, restarting unity brought it back in my case.

Comment: I think that it is not a off-topic, since to me it as just a mistake, removing some packages....

Comment: Why is this off-topic? The one specified reason is question for development version of Ubuntu which is not the case here. Is the real reason that 13.10 is no longer supported? Should that be a reason for question to be off-topic?

Comment: Answering my own question on why is this off-topic: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2448/2825

Answer (score 47):

Similar thing happened to me after upgrade to 13.10.
I found that this bug describes it:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1237361

I have it solved now, not sure if by installing system updates, by changing all related attributes in dconf-editor for node

> com.canonical.indicator.datetime

or just by restarting unity (Alt+F2 -> "unity --replace") as commenter in above mentioned bug said it may help.

So maybe try to play a bit with settings and then trying restarting unity would not be a bad idea either.

Comment: (Dunno how this got marked as a duplicate — Unity ≠ Gnome.) Replacing unity can cause the window manager to fail, so you get windows without controls that you can't move or close. I've had the most success with `sudo killall unity-panel-service`, which reinstates the clock immediately.

Comment: for me, `unity --replace` was enough. thanks for that!

Comment: @scruss, you don't need the sudo. You can just run `killall unity-panel-service` as described in the bug, [No clock in menu bar and can't edit Clock settings](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1228360).

Answer (score 16):

It's possible that it got uninstalled (most probably when you were trying to uninstall some other indicators). Try

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

And restart unity with

```
unity --replace
```

Then recheck your Clock settings. That should hopefully be the problem

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: After running above comment I needed to also restart unity with `unity --replace` and my clock was back

Answer (score 7):

For me check the clock settings solved the problem.. actually "Show a clock in the menu bar" was already checked, I had to uncecheck it, close the settings, reopen the settings, checked this option back and finally it worked.

Comment: It would have been good if you said where the clock settings were

Comment: @Anake: "System settings" -> "Time & Date" -> "Clock".

Comment: that checkbox is grayed and I cant interact with it!

Comment: @AquariusPower A hearty `killall unity-panel-service` solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @JonasGröger the `killall` was the solution